# Add/Update all child entities when updating parent entity in EF 5

Tags: entity-framework

I have one entity like `Supplier` and it has N level of child entities like `SupplierUser`, `Companyinformation`, `contactdetail`.

When I add first time with parent `Supplier` entity it inserts properly but when I update value in a child entity and call update from the parent entity, only the parent entity gets updated. So I need a code in which if I have parent entity object with all data of child and click on update it update parent data as well as child data.

Please reply, as this is really urgent

Answer (score 2):

You should handle this logic in your business layer, not in EF5. You can't assume that your ORM solution knows your business logic. If you post more code we may be able to help..

Comment: Yes I know but In EF5 If have parent and child data and when we call like  Client objClient = new Client() objClient.ModifiedByUserId = 1;
          objClient.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
          objClient.Customerinfo.FirstName ='jinesh'

          dbcontext.Client.insert(objClient);
          dbcontext.savechanges(); So this add Client as well as Customer detail so in this same way I need Update

Comment: you need this to be a 2 step process for sure. Save the client with the context, then add it.

Comment: But if we have N level of Child then how can we manage this in common Update Function?

Comment: can you give more code please inside the actual question.. not sure what you mean by n level of child

Comment: Not exactly N Level but we can say If I have Client as a Parent and then CUstomerInfo , Companyinfo as 1st level and Customerinfo has one child like UserProfile so I need to update all entity when Update Client because it has values of all object